# angular-cli external script not being run

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a project created with angular-cli v1.3.0 to which, I'm trying to add a simple JS file for use with the template I use. The problem is, the script is loaded to the site, but not run.

This is my `.angular-cli.json` file

```
...
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "./assets/js/remark.js"
],
...
```

Simple test scripts included:

./assets/js/remark.js:

```
console.log('Hello there')
```

or

```
(function () {
    console.log('Hello world')
})()
```

Is there any simple way to run this script or do I have to initialize it from inside the project, i.e. a TS file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the behaviour I'm looking for.

Comment: The generated file `scripts.bundle.js` contains all the code.

Comment: popper.js/dist/popper.min.js is an ESNext script, you probably want to use the UMD or the ESM builds.

Comment: @FezVrasta thanks, this solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

popper.js is ES Next script, you should use UMD or ESM version of it to fix this problem

```
...
"scripts": [
    ...,
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    ...
],
...
```